# Java: could not find or load main class test

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I have two `.java` files in a directory. One of them is an implementation of the `Vector` data structure, the other is a `test` class that contains a `main` method to test my `Vector` implementation. I'm trying to compile both files at the same time, so I did `javac -cp . *.java`, then when I run `java test`, I get `Error: Could not find or load main class test`, even though after compiling, I now have two `.java` files and two `.class` files. What do I do in order to run `test` from terminal?

Following is my `test.java` file:

```
package mStructures;

//import java.util.Vector;

public class test {

  public static void main(String argv[]){
  Vector<Integer> testV = new Vector<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 39; i++){
      System.out.printf("Capacity before adding %d: %d%n", i, testV.capacity());
      testV.add(i);
      System.out.printf("Capacity after adding %d: %d%n", i, testV.capacity());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You're right, I did `javac`, i just edit my question!

Comment: Add the test.java file please, in full.

Comment: Ah, you are using package mStructures - so the main class test can't be found. Best remove the package statement and try again. If you have the same package in the Vector, create a subdir mStructures and move the Vector.java into it.

Comment: So that did it. I removed `package mStructures` from both `Vector.java` and `test.java.` What if I want to keep the `package mStructures;` statement, what do I do?

Comment: All your classes should always be in a package. Including the Test class. Just use `java mStructures.Test`, because since the class is in the package `mStructures`, its name is `mStructures.Test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple things it's best to have Test.java (no package, note the import)

```
import mStruct.Vector;
public class Test { ... main ... }
```

in some directory and

```
package mStruct;
public class Vector { ... }
```

in its subdirectory mStruct.

Compile and exec:

```
javac Test.java mStruct/*.java
java Test
```

Comment: You may have to adjust the javac for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing - Your compilation command should have `javac` instead of `java`.
Secondly - include the same `cp` parameter as you have used while compiling the classes.

Comment: I compiled `javac`, there was a typo in the question. And I tried running `java -cp . test`, that didn't work either.

Comment: `Could not find or load main class test`

Comment: run using `java -cp . mStructures.test`.